# SimpleForm, I18n and Rails: Change namespace from de.simple_form.* to de.activerecord.*?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, simple-form

We just replaced FormTastic with SimpleForm, and while FormTastic used our translations in the namespace `de.activerecord.*`, SimpleForm seems to insist on `de.simple_form.*`. I googled around and also read the documentation, which interestingly has the following code snippet:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
        admin/user: User
    attributes:
        admin/user:
            name: Name
```

But nowhere else I can find more information about whether it is possible to make SimpleForm use `en.activerecord.*` as its namespace, or not.

So can I force SimpleForm to change its namespace? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is a very old question, but I just came across it when looking to do the same thing in SimpleForm 3.1.

SimpleForm now has a config option to specify the i18n prefix, it can be found at the bottom of `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`. You can simply configure it to use whatever scope you wish, eg. `activerecord` instead of `simple_form`:

```
# Defines which i18n scope will be used in Simple Form.
config.i18n_scope = 'activerecord'
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also the possibility to just alias/merge parts of a YAML tree:

```
de:
  active_record: &myAliasName
    models:
      contact:
          name: "Name"
          age: "Alter"
  simple_form:
    <<: *myAliasName
    another_key: "another_value"
```

results in:

```
{
  "de": {
    "simple_form": {
      "models": {
        "contact": {
          "age": "Alter", 
          "name": "Name"
        }
      }, 
      "another_key": "another_value"
    }, 
    "active_record": {
      "models": {
        "contact": {
          "age": "Alter", 
          "name": "Name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This may be a workaround for this problem, although it may be a little bit slower in performance I think.

Comment: haha who voted me down? in fact the provided answer was exactly what i was looking for, so i added it here in case somebody else searches too far for this simple problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check this file https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb#L161 I guess you could monkey patch it to change the namespace to yours.

Comment: +1, this line particularly: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb#L176